# 2D Projectile Trajectory Calculation with Radius

Tags: geometry, 2d, game-physics, trigonometry

I have a 2D game with a character (`Al`) trying to "save" another character (`Ho`) from an NPC (`Bu`).

`Al` and `Bu` have a constant speed (sally is stationary).

I needed to figure out how to calculate at what point `Al` should target in order to stop `Bu`

I was able to program this after reading [this tutorial](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/11/11/interception-of-a-linear-trajectory-with-constant-speed/). I converted some of the `pylab` code to `numpy`

```
def interception(Al, Bu, Ho, Sa, Sb):
    """ Returns ``(t_C, C)`` if A can catch B, before B 
    reaches H. Otherwise, returns ``None``. """
    A = np.array((Al["x"],Al["y"]))
    B = np.array((Bu["x"],Bu["y"]))
    H = np.array((Ho["x"],Ho["y"]))
    AB, AH, BH = np.linalg.norm(A-B), np.linalg.norm(A-H), np.linalg.norm(B-H)
    #if Ho["id"] =="1":
    #    print("AB=%s BH=%s"%(AB,BH), file=sys.stderr)
    if AB*BH == 0:
        return None, None
    sin_b = np.linalg.det(np.array((A-B,H-B))) / (AB*BH)
    sin_a = (Sb / Sa) * sin_b
    if abs(sin_a) > 1 :
        print("B moves too fast to be ever caught !", file=sys.stderr)
        return None, None
    else:
        sin_c = ( sin_a * math.sqrt(1 - sin_b**2)
                  + sin_b * math.sqrt(1 - sin_a**2) )
        BC = AB * (sin_a / sin_c)
        #if Ho["id"] ==1:
            #print(BC-BH, file=sys.stderr)
        if BC > BH:
           # print("B reaches H before interception by A !", BC,BH, file=sys.stderr)
            return None, None
        else:
            #print("A intercepted B !")
            t_C = BC / Sb
            C = B + BC * (H-B)/ BH
            return t_C, C
```

This works fine, but here is problem I'm trying to figure out. I want to adjust this `interception` function to have another parameter `Al_radius`. You see, `Al` has a gun and when `Bu` is in range of `Al_radius`, `Al` can shoot `Bu`

I am pretty sure that depending on `Al`'s range, his target position may change (for example, it may be faster to flank rather than to go directly toward the path between `Bu` and `Ho`).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there are two different sections of `Al`'s movement: the actual movement and the movement of the 'bullet'. Note that I am assuming the bullet fires and hits the target instantly. Since we want to minimise the time taken, a straight line path is the best solution. I.e. `Al`'s movement (from `A` to `D`) and the trajectory of the 'bullet' bullet are in a straight line.

[image]

We can still use the same triangle from the tutorial. The only difference is that we now have a new equation for AC to account for the range of the gun (denoted as the circle).

[image].

Using the cosine rule:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Multiply and rearrange:

[image]

If [image], the solution is:

[image]

Otherwise the solution to the quadratic equation is:

[image]

As with your example:
[image]

And point C can be calculated the same way as before:
[image]